# Frame ticks of array plot given by a list

Tags: plotting, matrix

Suppose I have an array plot like this:

```
M = RandomReal[1, {5, 10}];

ArrayPlot[M, FrameTicks -> Automatic]
```

[image]

How can I make it so that the frame ticks are given by a list, like:

```
x={2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};

y={10,11,12,13,14};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
M = RandomReal[1, {5, 10}];
x = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};
y = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14};

{xticks, yticks} = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, #] & /@ {x, y};

ArrayPlot[M, FrameTicks -> {{yticks, yticks}, {xticks, xticks}}]
```

[image]

You can also use

```
{yticks2, xticks2} = Thread /@ Thread[{Range[Dimensions[M]], {y, x}}];

{yticks2, xticks2} == {yticks, xticks}
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Alternative approach is to reverse the rows of `M` and use the options [`DataRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) and [`DataReversed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataReversed.html) and use `{{y,y},{x,x}}` as `FrameTicks`:

```
ArrayPlot[Reverse @ M, 
 DataReversed -> True, 
 DataRange -> MinMax /@ {x, y}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{y, y}, {x, x}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Comment: Image are not identical?

Comment: Thank you @OkkesDulgerci. Updated to get identical images.